# Probability crash course

Tags: probability, reference-request, soft-question, machine-learning

These holidays (two weeks) I need to learn probability applied to Machine Learning.

Reading a paper, I have found this: *"The training objective is thus to minimize the pixel-wise multi-class crossentropy loss ..."*, and I have no idea about what it is, so I realize that I need to learn probability.

**NOTE**: I know what is a loss function and how to minimize it. My problem is with *crossentropy*. I've been searching about it and it is related to information theory and with probability.

Do you know any good probability crash course?

Comment: This is quite an endeavor to complete in two weeks, [this](https://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Recognition-Learning-Information-Statistics/dp/0387310738) is friendly enough if you want to take a look. That being said, I don't think you need need to take a whole course in probability to translate that sentence, in a nutshell it just means that you need to minimize a function, turns out that function has a long name, but other than that it is just an optimization problem

Comment: You can get an intuitive understanding of the cross-entropy loss function directly, quite quickly, without taking an entire course in probability and without knowing anything about information theory. Just read this question and the answer I posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389976/what-is-the-motivation-for-using-cross-entropy-to-compare-two-probability-vector

Comment: There are a lot of suggestions about books for probability and machine learning: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22machine+learning%22+%22probability%22+%22book%22

Comment: @caverac Thanks for your comment but I know what is a loss function and how to minimize it. My problem is with crossentropy. I've been searching about it and it is related to information theory and with probability. Thanks a lot.